# How to handle unused Managed Metadata Terms without a WssId?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata, taxonomy

**The Problem**

We upload (large amounts of) files to SharePoint using FrontPage RPC (*put documents* call). As far as we've been able to find out, setting the value of taxonomy fields through this protocol requires their *WssId*.

The problem is that unless terms have been explicitly used before on a listitem, they don´t seem to *have* a WSS ID. This causes uploading documents with previously unused metadata terms to fail.

**The Code**

The call [TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getwssidsofterm.aspx) in the code snippet below simply doesn´t return an ID for those terms.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite( "http://some.site.com/foo/bar" );
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession( site ); 
TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[new Guid( "3ead46e7-6bb2-4a54-8cf5-497fc7229697" )];
TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet( new Guid( "f21ac592-5e51-49d0-88a8-50be7682de55" ) );
Guid termId = new Guid( "a40d53ed-a017-4fcd-a2f3-4c709272eee4" );

int[] wssIds = TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm( site, termStore.Id, termSet.Id, termId, false, 1);

foreach( int wssId in wssIds )
{
    Console.WriteLine( wssId );
}
```

We also tried querying the taxonomy hidden list directly, with similar results.

**The Cry For Help**

Both confirmation and advice on how to tackle this would be appreciated. I see three possible routes to a solution:

- Change the way we are uploading, either by uploading the terms in a different way, or by switching to a different protocol.

  Query for the metadata WssIds in a different way. One that works for unused terms.

  Write/find a tool to preresolve WssIds for all terms. Suggestions on how to do this elegantly are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

setting the WssID value to -1 should help you. I had similar problem (copying documents containing metadata fields) between two different web applications. I've spent many hours on solving strange metadata issues. In the end, setting the value to -1 have solved all my issues. Even if the GetWssIdsOfTerm returns a value, I've used -1 and it works correctly.
Probably there is some background logic that will tak care of the WssId.

Radek